# Why Maximum Field Length in Views Module(drupal) doesnt changes the view?

Tags: drupal-6, view

The "Trim this field to a maximum length" option is giving me some pretty unexpected and confusing results. I have decided I want my field length to be cut
off after 35 characters. However when I specify this amount in the "Maximum Length" text box and save the view, the field is completely cut off, everything
is gone.

So as a test I raised the limit to 100 characters, this gave me some of the field. However I don't know where Views is getting the 100 characters from?
What does it consider a character to be?

The next issue is that I have many fields in my grid (in a descending order), and the 100 characters limit I've set is behaving differently on each field.
I would expect all the fields to be the same length, however some are drastically shorter than others.

I can't get my head around this at all! Help?!

Answer (score 0):

Can the field have html code? If so, it may examplain your issue. 
This trim tool counts all characters, be it html code or the text to display.

Best option for you might be to mark the option below trim checkbox. 
Remove HTML tags